# Get file name and length when transmit file using java socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am going to transmit a file(for example: abc.jpg) using **Java** socket:

What I can:

- Establish a socket connection with other side
- Send file content successfully

What I want:

- Let other side know file name(use the same file name to store file) and file length(used to check if transmit successfully) in advance.

My idea:

- What I can come up is sending file name and file length before sending file content using the same socket connection

Problem:

- As different type of information(file name, file length, and file content) should be send through the same socket connection, how does the other side know what I am transmitting?

Does anyone have any idea about how to let other side know the file name and file length? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is called TLV : type (or tag), length, value. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value

Comment: You just have to establish "own protocol" for sending files stating for both sides to know that they have to expect name and size values at the beginning of transmition. Is it about other side knowing the size and filename BEFORE actual transfer occure or does that came only as additional data?

Comment: @Antoniossss Thank you for your quick answer, I want the other side know file name and size as additional data. I do not want to send file name and size and file content in more than one request(respone). Is there any simple ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, according to your comment, the most simple way to do this is to create container class that is serializable and send it. Eg.

```
public class FileContainer implements Serializable{

private String filename;
private Integer size;
private byte[] data;

//proper getters and setters
}
```

Later on, read your file into byte array, put it into container, and serialize it via socket

```
FileContainer fc=new FileContainer();
//TODO: read file and set proper fields in fc
ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(fc);

//and on receiving side

ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
FileContainer fc=in.readObject(); // here you will need to add type casting
```

and that is it.

You have mentioned as well that you want to check if the data is correct. If it is TCP connection, you don't have to worry about as data corectness is guaranteed by the protocol itself. Both sides will get exception in case if something is wrong. Situation is different however in UDP communications.

Comment: OK, got that. but I have another question using this way, How about transmit a larger file, for example: 50MB, if using writeObject and readObject, would the whole file be loaded to memory as a java object? then this object would become very large, I am worry about memory because I use an android phone to establish a WiFi-Direct connection with another android phone.

Comment: in case of large files you should use direct streaming. In such case, I would send name, and size first, and than read file and write into stream using 1kb exchange buffer. The other side will have to expect that after name and size (it still can be serialized data container but without file data) will come stream of file data.

Comment: Thank you so much! Does that mean I need to send multiple request for every file? I think the best way is to define a "protocol" for both sides as you suggested at the beginning. In this way, we can only send one request and let other side to parse byte[] data from stream. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: That's why protocols are made for. No problem

Comment: @Alvis could you please share the code to send the file name with the file if you have done?

Comment: @KAMALVERMA As Antoniossss suggested, I have implemented my own "protocal" to achieve this. The first 4 bytes is an int value which represents the length of file name(lets call it fileNameLength), the next fileNameLength bytes are the name data, the next 8 bytes is a long value represents the fileLength(lets call it fileLength), and the next fileLength is the file content.

Comment: @KAMALVERMA BTW, how do you achieve this? Any idea is welcomed

Comment: @Alvis i just send the name of the file .you just give me your email id will mail you the clientsocket and serversocket code for this .

Comment: @KAMALVERMA you can send email to wanxiaolong100@gmail.com, thanks